# Notice: Undefined index: image - unable to find the error

Tags: php, mysql, sql, html, xampp

here is my error.i dont know why it is not working.i checked all the parts but i was unable to find the error.

> Notice: Undefined index: image in C:\xampp\htdocs\Final\places\Ressave.php on line 27

here is my html code that pass the name of input:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="Ressave.php" method="POST" autocomplete="on">
<div class="well">
   <legend>Photos</legend>
      <div class="control-group">
         <label class="control-label">Upload Photo: </label>
             <div class="controls">
                   <input name="image" type="file" />
             </div>   
     </div>
</div>

            <div class="form-actions">

              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>

              <button type="button" class="btn">Cancel</button>

            </div>

        </form>
```

Ressave.php is here and can not recieve the name here,so the error occure.....

```
<?php
{       //  Secure Connection Script
    include('../Secure/dbConfig.php'); 
    $dbSuccess = false;
    $dbConnected = mysql_connect($db['hostname'],$db['username'],$db['password']);

    if ($dbConnected) {     
        $dbSelected = mysql_select_db($db['database'],$dbConnected);
        if ($dbSelected) {
            $dbSuccess = true;
        } else {
            echo "DB Selection FAILed";
        }
    } else {
            echo "MySQL Connection FAILed";
    }
    //  END Secure Connection Script
}
if(! $dbConnected )
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}


{               // File Properties

$file = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];   //Error comes from here(here is the prob!)


if(!isset($file))

    echo "Please Choose an Image.";

else  {
        $image = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']));

        $image_size = getimagesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);   

        if($image_size == FALSE)
            echo "That is not an image.";
        else 
        {
                $lastid = mysql_insert_id();
                echo "Image Uploaded.";             
        }
}

}

{           //join the post values into comma separated 

    $features = mysql_real_escape_string(implode(',', $_POST['features']));
    $parking = mysql_real_escape_string(implode(',', $_POST['parking']));   
    $noise = mysql_real_escape_string(implode(',', $_POST['noise']));       
    $good_for = mysql_real_escape_string(implode(',', $_POST['good_for']));
    $ambience = mysql_real_escape_string(implode(',', $_POST['ambience']));
    $alcohol = mysql_real_escape_string(implode(',', $_POST['alcohol']));


}


$sql =  "INSERT INTO prestaurant ( ResName, Rating, Food_serve, Features, Parking, noise, Good_For, Ambience, Alcohol, Addition_info, Name, Address1, Zipcode1, Address2, Zipcode2, Address3, Zipcode3, City, Mobile, phone1, phone2, phone3, phone4, Email1, Email2, Fax, Website, image)". 
        "VALUES ('$_POST[restaurant_name]','$_POST[star_rating]','$_POST[food_served]','$features','$parking','$noise','$good_for','$ambience','$alcohol','$_POST[description]','$_POST[name]','$_POST[address1]','$_POST[zipcode1]','$_POST[address2]','$_POST[zipcode2]','$_POST[address3]','$_POST[zipcode3]','$_POST[city]','$_POST[mobile]','$_POST[phone1]','$_POST[phone2]','$_POST[phone3]','$_POST[phone4]','$_POST[email1]','$_POST[email2]','$_POST[fax]','$_POST[url]','$image')";


mysql_select_db('place');
$retval = mysql_query( $sql );
if(! $retval )
{    
  die('Could not enter data: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo "Entered data successfully\n";
mysql_close($dbConnected);
?>
```

Comment: are you getting an error even when you select a valid image file to upload?

Comment: I think you might have some extra and redundant curly braces in your code ( {} ) can you try cleaning up your code and see if it makes any change? Also, I don't see any code that would actually upload the file to your server.

Comment: you khow the same code work in other place but when im using it in here i dont know why im getting error

Comment: @EniGma I noticed in `if(!isset($file)) echo "Please Choose an Image.";` that there are no opening or closing braces. That could be a factor here. Which should read as  `if(!isset($file)) { echo "Please Choose an Image."; }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If a file was not uploaded the $_FILES array will be empty. Specifically, if the file `image` was not uploaded, `$_FILES['image']` will not be set.

So

```
$file = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];   //Error comes from here(here is the prob!)
```

should be:

```
if(empty($_FILES) || !isset($_FILES['image']))
```

**update**

You will also have issues because you're missing the `enctype` attribute on your form:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="Ressave.php" method="POST" autocomplete="on" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Comment: the error is 

    Array ( ) Please Choose an Image.
    Notice: Undefined variable: image in         C:\xampp\htdocs\Final\places\Ressave.php on line 64

Comment: my same code will work other place but it is not working in this part of my code

Comment: @JohnConde I'm starting to wonder whether the OP wants a simple reference to an uploaded file, or if the OP wants the file uploaded to an actual folder. (using `move_uploaded_file`) which is not in the OP's code.

Comment: when i use  print_r($_POST['image']); it will show the name of the image like(winter.jpg)

Comment: @EniGma What (exactly) works? What happened for it to suddenly work?

Comment: i use john's code (if(empty($_FILES) || !isset($_FILES['image']))) and i it worked...

Comment: @EniGma That's great, glad to hear it. Cheers

Comment: ^--- that's for you @JohnConde (am sure) ;-)

Comment: that thanx was for you either ...:)

Answer (score 3):

In order to be able to process files in your form you need to add the enctype attribute.

```
<form method='POST' enctype='multipart/form-data' >
```

Comment: @EniGma Whether it makes a difference or not, it must be in your form.

Comment: @EniGma Look at my comment also, there's something about your `if` condition http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18747542/notice-undefined-index-image-unable-to-find-the-error#comment27633396_18747542

Answer (score 0):

Hey i guess you have forgotten one important setting in form
enctype="multipart/form-data" this option is used when used with files eg image file etc

```
<form name="image" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Apart from that to extract the contents of the file you can use following options

```
$tmp_img_path = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
$img_name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
```

to print all the content of a file use:

```
print_r($_POST['image']);
```

Answer (score 0):

this is the code i have which successfully insert the data into mysql and retrieve from the DB.

"Index.PHP"

```
<html>
<head>
<title>PHP & MySQL: Upload an image</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="index.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
File: <input type="file" name="image" /><input type="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>

<?php
mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("registrations") or die(mysql_error());
if(!isset($_FILES['image']))
{
echo 'Please select an image.';
}
else {
$image = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']));
echo $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
$image_name = addslashes($_FILES['image']['name']);
$image_size = getimagesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);

if($image_size==FALSE){
echo "That's not an image.";
} else {
if(!$insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO test_image VALUES ('','$image_name','$image')"))
     {
 echo "Problem uploading image.";
 } else {
  $lastid = mysql_insert_id();
  echo "Image uploaded.<p />Your image:<p /><img src=get.php?id=$lastid>";
  }
}

  }
?>
</body>
</html>
```

this is get.PHP

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("registrations") or die(mysql_error());
$id = addslashes($_REQUEST['id']);
$image = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM test_image WHERE id=$id");
$image = mysql_fetch_assoc($image);
$image = $image['image'];
header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
echo $image;
?>
```

NOTE:-  please changes your DB and table name accordingly..
Thanks,
Santanu