# Upload pictures to server directory using php

Tags: php, image, upload, directory, server

I have a server apache and mysql at my friend's house, i can connect to both of them, but i want to upload pictures from my Macbook to my directory in the server (Ubuntu), i have some issues and tried many things but any of them worked, please help me thanks :)

The html form:

```
<html>
        <head>
        </head>

        <body>
                <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="php.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        <input type="file" name="img"/>
                        <input type="submit"/>
                </form>
        </body>

</html>
```

The php :

```
    <html>

<head> <meta charset="UTF-8"/> </head>

</html>


<?php


$bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=***.***.***.***;port:****;dbname=**********', '*******', '**********',array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));


echo $_FILES['img']['name'];

$target1 = "/home/knight/";
$target = $target1 . basename( $_FILES['img']['name']);

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['img']['tmp_name'], $target))
{

//Tells you if its all ok
echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). " has been uploaded, and your information has been added to the directory";
}
else {

//Gives and error if its not
echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file.";
}
?>
```

Comment: So tell us what you tried so we dont waste time suggesting the same things. Also have you looked at the apache and php error logs on the server. They may tell you a lot.

Comment: Lets assume that you gave access to apache user to write on your home folder `/home/knight/`. Is this what you want? because almost everyone have right to write on your home folder.

Comment: The upload directory must be 777 writable. What exactly is your error?

Comment: copy this into your code and tell us the error
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');

Comment: I tried without the PDO, with another directory, with another file, changing the name of input name, and look for answer around internet but i didn't find anything :/

Comment: you dont need pdo as you ar enot using a DB

Comment: check with this function if the file is uploaded and tell us the result is_uploaded_file($_FILES['img']['tmp_name']);

Comment: With the error reporting and quoting the line with the PDO, it's telling me:


Notice: Undefined index: img in /var/www/html/tewt/php.php on line 18

Notice: Undefined index: img in /var/www/html/tewt/php.php on line 20

Comment: Other users had this problem before.
Please check this [link][1] or [this one][2].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18747542/notice-undefined-index-image-unable-to-find-the-error
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18887004/undefined-index-in-file-while-uploading-image